# Por que no me funciona este switch case

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando hacer un switch case, pero no llego a conseguir que me funcione bien.

```
var countCarrit = 0;

$(".zona_productos").on('click', '.anadirCarrito',function(e) {

  switch(countCarrit) {
            
    case (countCarrit = 0):
     ......
    break;

    case (countCarrit > 1 && countCarrit < 14):
     .....
    break;
    case (countCarrit < 14):
     .....
    break;
});
```

He puesto un `console.log(countCarrit);` cuando hago click en `.zona_productos`. Y el primer click si que hace el primer case, pero ya a partir de ahí me cambia la variable `countCarrit` a 14, es como si lo que estoy haciendo es renombrar la variable.

Esta claro que lo estoy haciendo mal, pero si lo hago con `if` y `else if` tampoco me sale bien.

Gracias

Comment: La respuesta tiene que ir en la seccion de respuestas.. igual, tu codigo tiene un error (countCarrit = 0 hace que valga 0) y no sabemos que hay dentro del switch...

Comment: EL switch valida el contenido de la variable. Neto, tienes un montón de casos en los que validas si countCarrit es true, false, true, false,... porque validas la variable contra el resultado de la expresión lógica :D El switch ya tiene la lógica para que le digas case 0, case 1... case 10. Sugiero leas la documentación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como mencionan en los comentarios, el problema es que no estás comparando el valor sino asignando cero aquí: `case (countCarrit = 0):`

Debería ser `case (countCarrit == 0):` o `case (countCarrit === 0):` o mejor aún `case 0:`

Recuerda que:

- `=` es para asignación de valores a variables
- `==` es para comparación en modo no estricto *solo el valor sin importar el tipo de dato*
- `===` es para comparación en modo estricto *valor y tipo de dato*

De cualquier modo, te sugiero usar `if else` en lugar se `switch` para el caso que planteas.

```
var countCarrit = 0;

$(".zona_productos").on('click', '.anadirCarrito',function(e) {

  if (countCarrit == 0) {
     .....
  } else if (countCarrit >= 1 && countCarrit <= 14){
     .....
  } else if (countCarrit > 14){
     .....
  }
});
```